# Why does a function, that returns Function.prototype.call() acts differently here?

Tags: javascript, call

```
> Array.prototype.slice.call('1, 2, 3');
// returns: [ '1', ',', ' ', '2', ',', ' ', '3' ]
```

But:

```
> function toArray() {
... return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
... };

> let some = toArray('1, 2, 3');
> some    // returns [ '1, 2, 3' ]
```

Why is that? It's the same thing passed as argument, but the results are different.

Comment: in the second case, `arguments` is an array with a single element, not a string.

Comment: @StephenThomas: Not an array, but array-like.

Comment: Did you do `console.dir(arguments)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`arguments != '1, 2, 3'`.

`arguments` is an array-like object containing *all* the arguments, it isn't the first argument.

```
return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments[0]);
```

… would be equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

In first example `slice` is called with string passed as argument. This way it is treated as a array of characters. because you have not provided starting position of slice, the whole array is returned. In the second example `slice` is called with `arguments` object which is array-like structure. So you have array(-like) with string on index 0. Because, again, you have not provided beginning index, array with one item is returned.